# REST Assured - How to log Request only if response contains an HTTP error

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured

I'm using test assured to load a reasonable large set of test data into my application under test.

I want to log the request and response details for ONLY the requests that generate an error response (HTTP 4xx or 5xx)

I've tried these snippets but end up with ALL requests logged and only the error responses logged. The problem is that my log files become really large and it's causing issues in Jenkins. I just want to see the errors and the request that caused them.

```
    RequestSpecBuilder build = new RequestSpecBuilder();
    build.addFilter(new ErrorLoggingFilter()).log(LogDetail.ALL);
    requestSpec = build.build();

    RequestSpecBuilder build = new RequestSpecBuilder();
    build.log(LogDetail.ALL).addFilter(new ErrorLoggingFilter());
    requestSpec = build.build();
```

Comment: workaround: Log rotation. Increase log level. Create some class for log (allow logging only this class) and disable rest of them.

Answer (score 4):

You can create your own filter by implementing `io.restassured.filter.Filter` interface:

```
  public class FailedRequestFilter implements Filter {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FailedRequestFilter.class.getName());

    @Override
    public Response filter(FilterableRequestSpecification requestSpec, FilterableResponseSpecification responseSpec, FilterContext ctx) {
      Response response = ctx.next(requestSpec, responseSpec);
      if (response.statusCode() >= 400) {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, requestSpec.getMethod() + " " + requestSpec.getURI() + " => " +
            response.getStatusCode() + " " + response.getStatusLine());
      }
      return response;
    }
  }
```

And then use it in your requests:

```
RestAssured.given()
    .filter(new FailedRequestFilter())
    .when()
    .get("http://www.example.com");
```

Using Java 8 lambda expression can also work:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("SomeLoggerName");
RestAssured.given()
    .filter(
        (request, response, ctx) -> {
          Response resp = ctx.next(request, response);
          if (resp.statusCode() >= 400) {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, request.getMethod() + " " + request.getURI() + " => "
                + response.getStatusCode() + " " + response.getStatusLine());
          }
          return resp;
        })
    .when()
    .get("http://wwww.example.com");
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but I can't quite make this work. Can you expand your example and explain where the logger object is initiated?

Comment: @elroso it's actually up to you where and how you want to instantiate logger. it can be inside a filter class or maybe a global one. or even passing logger instance in FailedRequestFilter constructor (if that works for you)

Answer (score 0):

I created an optional config parameter to enable failure logging for debugging failing tests:

```
public static Response sendRequest(Method method, String url, RequestSpecification spec, Integer expectedStatus) {
        try {
            ValidatableResponse response = given().spec(spec).request(method, new URL(url)).then();
            if (getConfig().restAssuredDebuggingEnabled()) {
                response.log().all();
            }
            if (expectedStatus != null) {
                response.statusCode(expectedStatus);
            }
            return response.extract().response();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(method + " call to " + url + " failed", ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `.log(LogDetail.ALL)` in your RequestSpecBuilder. This method adds `new RequestLoggingFilter` to your filter chain. It causes your request to be logged.

See `log` method [source code](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/blob/718ad4b684656547a4561c1bbbbcfbec409efadf/rest-assured/src/main/java/io/restassured/builder/RequestSpecBuilder.java#L1173)